# Sorting by relevance with Laravel Collections whereHas()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Take this working code. It firstly searches the `users` table for a keyword and then it will use the `whereHas()` method to search the pivot table `category_user` for any users assigned to a given category based on a search. This works nicely, all entries are retrieved.

So to be absolutely clear 3 tables are in use, `users`, `categories` and `category_user`.

I am using Laravel collections `sortByDesc()` to order the entries based on relevance. So if **category 1**, **category 2** and a keyword of **my example search term** were all stored against **user 1** and only **category 1** was stored against **user 2**, **user 1** would display first in the results.

The below code does exactly this but **ONLY** on the `users` table. I Have had a good scan around and cannot seem a way to work this solution into this type of query, due to the uniqueness of the way I need to order. Can anyone advise any methods?

```
//props for sortByDesc
$props = ['name', 'slug', 'location', 'company_name', 'biography', 'usually_active'];

//Search Query
//1. Search users table for keywords
//2. use whereHas() to search pivot table of categories for keyword and filters selected
//3. use sortByDesc collections to order results based number of matches, most matches ordered at the top
$search_results = User::where('approved', '=', 1)
->where('user_type_id', '=', 1)
->orWhere(function ($q) use ($search_items) {        
    
    //search users tables
    foreach ($search_items as $value) {
        $q->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhere('location', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhere('company_name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhere('biography', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhere('usually_active', 'like', "%{$value}%");
    }

})->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use($search_items) {
    
    //search categories table
    if(!empty($search_items)):
        $q->whereIn('name', $search_items);
        $q->orWhereIn('slug', $search_items);
    endif;

//Now we sort based on best matches
})->get()->sortByDesc(function($i, $k) use ($search_items, $props) {
    
    // The bigger the weight, the higher the record
    $weight = 0;

    // Iterate through search terms
    foreach($search_items as $item) {
        foreach($props as $prop) { 
            if(strpos($i->{$prop}, $item) !== false)
                $weight += 1; // Increase weight if the search term is found
        }
    }

    return $weight;
});

//get the results and paginate
$search_results = $search_results->values()->all();
$search_results = $this->paginate($search_results);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the `withCount()` method in order to determine the number of categories stored against a user in the pivot table. I could then use `categories_count` returned with each item to order the entries based on the number of tagged categories per user.

```
$search_results = User::where('approved', '=', 1)
    ->where('user_type_id', '=', 1)
    ->where(function ($q) use ($search_items) {        
    
        //search users tables
        foreach ($search_items as $value) {
            $q->orWhere('users.name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
            $q->orWhere('users.location', 'like', "%{$value}%");
            $q->orWhere('users.company_name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
            $q->orWhere('users.biography', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        }

    })->orWhereHas('categories', function ($q) use($search_items) {

        if(!empty($search_items)):
            $q->whereIn('name', $search_items);
            $q->orWhereIn('slug', $search_items);
        endif;

    //Now we sort based on best matches
    })->withCount([
        'categories' => function ($q) use($search_items) {
            
            //search categories table
            if(!empty($search_items)):
                $q->whereIn('name', $search_items);
                $q->orWhereIn('slug', $search_items);
            endif;
        }

    ])->orderByDesc('categories_count')->paginate(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

Add a select for the categories columns you want to filter. Be careful, the resulting dataset will contain columns like `categories.name` so you may want to adjust keys in your `search_items` accordingly or alias the added select.

To do so you need to join the categories table in the query, I guessed your foreign keys but feel free to correct them in the join clause to match what you have in database.

Doing so you can then simplify your where clauses in only one

```
<?
User::join('categories', 'user.categories_id', '=', 'categories.id')
where('approved', '=', 1)
->where('user_type_id', '=', 1)
->orWhere(function ($q) use ($search_items) {        
    
    //search users tables
    foreach ($search_items as $value) {
        $q->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhere('location', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhere('company_name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhere('biography', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhere('usually_active', 'like', "%{$value}%");
        $q->orWhereIn('categories.name', $search_items);
        $q->orWhereIn('categories.slug', $search_items);
    }

})
// Add the columns you want to sort on
->addSelect(['categories.name', 'categories.slug']) 
->get()->sortByDesc(function($i, $k) use ($search_items, $props) {
    
    // The bigger the weight, the higher the record
    $weight = 0;

    // Iterate through search terms
    foreach($search_items as $item) {
        foreach($props as $prop) { 
            if(strpos($i->{$prop}, $item) !== false)
                $weight += 1; // Increase weight if the search term is found
        }
    }

    return $weight;
});
```

### Longer answer:

When you start your query from a model, in your case, `User`, eloquent automatically adds this model's columns to the select, regardless of the relations that are defined on the model.

If you want to access columns on the joined tables, you need to manually add them to the select with `->addSelect([...])`.

You can read more about it on the official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#specifying-a-select-clause

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I feel this is on the correct path, when I add in the ->addSelect(['categories.name', 'categories.slug']) it is trying to pull categories.name and categories.slug from the users table, not the categories table. Is there anything additional that is required in order to make that appraoch work?

Comment: Oh, maybe you need to add a join to the categories table then, I'll edit my answer

Comment: I've added the join and simplified the where clause as categories fields are now available in the query

Comment: Does the pivot table need to be joined instead or as well as categories? as the categories table stores nothing on the user, the category_user pivot table does.

Comment: Oh there is a pivot ? So you have many categories per user ?
In this case, what exactly is the intended result in the end ?
One line per user or one line per category ?
Maybe it could be more clear with a database schema and the intended data result example

Comment: But I think that for what you are trying to do, the only way is to use joins all th way through the pivot, to rework yout conditions accordingly and then to apply the ordering and maybe even a grouping depending on the end result you expect

Comment: I found a solution, just posted the answer.

Comment: Nice ! Reading the solution I think I missed a part of your problematic ! Glad you found the way